# How to output whole number float in YAML?

Tags: php, symfony, floating-point, yaml

I'm using the [Symfony YAML component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html). If I output data from my database, numbers come up as strings so I'm converting them to the appropriate type (int or float) using `filter_var`.

However, outputting floats that are whole numbers like `7.0` instead outputs `!!float 7`. The `7.0` is parsed perfectly fine as a float in PHP, it only changes it on output.

Example code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$yaml = 'test: { PHP: 7.0, MySQL: 5.5 }';
echo Yaml::dump(Yaml::parse($yaml));
```

Output:

```
test:
    PHP: !!float 7
    MySQL: 5.5
```

But I want:

```
test:
    PHP: 7.0
    MySQL: 5.5
```

Is there a way to do this? Can't see anything in the options.

Comment: Please refer :https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#explicit-typing

Comment: What do you need that for? Parsing file with Symfony YAML will return the float value need

Comment: @TomášVotruba Because I want the YAML file to be human-readable, and `7.0` is more readable.

Comment: I see. I had the same feeling before and tried to change it. But it was not worth my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to influence how a floating point value is dumped. The corresponding code from the Yaml component looks like this:

```
if (\is_float($value)) {
    $repr = (string) $value;
    if (is_infinite($value)) {
        $repr = str_ireplace('INF', '.Inf', $repr);
    } elseif (floor($value) == $value && $repr == $value) {
        // Preserve float data type since storing a whole number will result in integer value.
        $repr = '!!float '.$repr;
    }
} else {
    $repr = \is_string($value) ? "'$value'" : (string) $value;
}
```

Comment: For future reference, I solved this by manually replacing the output from `Yaml::dump()` with the float value, using: `preg_replace('#!!float (\d+)#', '\1.0', $yamlStr)`